Why Ad Click Aggregation is done during insertion
In most of the system design of an "Ad Click Aggregation" system, the click aggregation is performed by some batch processor (Apache Spark) and then inserted into the database.
However, I wonder why this processing is done during insertion and why the data is not inserted into a time series database and perform the aggregation at the time of reading.
I do understand that with pre-processing the query speed will be much faster but the time taken by the pre-processing will make the data available in the database with a delay. Also, we need to take care of duplicate processing.
Can someone please explain why query time aggregation is not considered?
